# How to use comment line in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to comment line for single line in asp.net.Now I use multi line comment line <%--  --%>.Is any other way to comment single line.
In php I use comment like // for single line.
I use single line comment for future verification.Without comment line my get confused.

Comment: Does an apostrophe (') work?

Comment: In Visual Studio use ctrl+k+c to comment and ctrl+k+u to uncomment. Multiple and single lines will be taken care by IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On code behind:**

```
// this is comment
/* This is comment */
```

**on .aspx page:**

```
<!-- This is comment-->
```